# Restrict to access method in derived class

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0

I want to restrict the access of base class method in my derived class. Is this possible?

```
class Class1 
    {
        protected virtual void Method()
    {

    }
}

class Class2 : Class1
{
    protected override void Method()
    {
        base.Method();
    }

}

class  Class3 : Class2
{
    public Class3()
    {
        //I want to restrict to use this method in this class alone
        this.Method(); 
    }

}
```

But it must be derived from base class.

Comment: The solution you are looking for would allow to call base.Method(); or not ?

Comment: Can you describe why you wish to make this restriction? There is probably a better way to do what you want.

Answer (score 7):

> This was asked in my interview and to my friends also in some other interviews. But they told as it possible to do restrict this.

What you're asking about is, as other answers note, not possible in C#.  So, some hypotheses:

- The interviewers incorrectly believe this is possible.
- The interviewers know it is impossible and want to see whether you know that.
- The interviewers did a poor job of asking the question; the question they tried to ask is different than the question you posed here.
- The interviewers know it is impossible but want to see if you can ask probing questions -- like "why do you want to do this?" -- in order to see if you're the sort of person who concentrates on the technical issue, or whether you actually try to find out the user-driven justification for writing software.

Were I asked the question as posed I would push back with "so what you're telling me is you've designed a class hierarchy with a method that is *so broken* that only certain classes can use it properly, and it must only be used by those classes, right?  **Don't design methods like that**.  The question should not be *how to stop my coworkers and customers from using this badly designed method*. The question should be *how to fix the method so that it is useful to everyone*."

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way in C# to do this natively.

If you make the method private, then no subclass can access it. That doesn't sound like what you want. If it is protected as now, even if you hide it in class2, class3 will still have access to Method() of class1.

Essentially, there needs to be a way for the base class to know whether to allow or restrict access.

One way could be using Interfaces; have the child class implement an IAccessRestricted empty interface, and the base class method can be made generic. When T implements IAccessRestricted, the base class method just returns.

The problem with this or anything similar is that the control of the access is still not really in the base class. It is in the class that requires the restriction. So it is kind of pointless.

Thus, if the requirement is that some subclasses CAN access, while some cannot, I would make the base class not have that method, and then add an interim base class that does, and then subclassess of each either will, or will not, have access to Method().

```
    class BaseWithOutMethod 
    {

    }

    class BaseWithMethod : BaseWithOutMethod
    {
        protected virtual void Method()
        {
            // do method stuff
        }
    }

    class Class2 : BaseWithMethod
    {
        protected override void Method()
        {
            base.Method();
        }
    }

    class Class3 : BaseWithOutMethod
    {
        public Class3()
        {
            // cannot access Method because it is not in this base class
        }
    }
```

Comment: On this solution you no longer have a inheritance between class2 and class3. But the idea behind it is great.

Comment: True, very good point. This is definitely a design issue where some compromise will need to be made if it is to be effective. There is probably a solution with reflection in there somewhere, but it still does not truly restrict the access. Selective access to a protected member is just not what C# does :)

Comment: "Selective access to a protected member is just not what C# does" you mean the "hack" i suggested?

Comment: Well the hack is one way, just like using reflection and then throwing an exception would be, or using interfaces, or hard-coding the classnames that are not allowed. Doesn't matter how it's implemented, if a member is protected, then all subclasses of that class will always see it and be able to access and call it, if it is present. So any solution which uses some mechanism (or hack) to restrict the access isn't going to be fool proof. Even with using different base classes, if they are in the same DLL what stops a programmer from just always subclassing the BaseClassWithMethod.

Comment: "Selective access to a protected member" is my interpretation of what the OP is attempting to accomplish. Both what you suggested and what I suggested (they are all hacks) are possible solutions to work around the fact that what OP wants doesn't exist in C#.

Comment: you are right there.  but you know... at some point reflection even allow you to call private stuff. When you hit the darkside of Reflection there is bearly no limit.... unless you compile into an dll with some specific instruction to encrpyt everything.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** `base.Method();` is a valid call.

You can override the class3's Method and throw an exception

**Case 2:** You want to prevent the class 3 to use this method at ALL cost.

You are currently facing a design issue. The solution is then a case by case issue. Keep in mind that a child class can be considered as a parent class. 
In the current scenario where class1's Method implementation is empty. Declare it abstract. In Class2 keep it abstract but implement all what you want and then class3 would be able to "implement" it with no code at all. a Class4 would exist to fill the missing chunk of code from Class2.

An other "hack" that could be done. I want you to know that this is a HACK and reflect some design flaws.  Add yourself a protected boolean value in class1. At the very start of Class1's implementation of Method, you check the value of the bool and either run the code or throw an exception.   You can then in class3 set that boolean to false and be sure that it will not be able to run the code from parent classes.

An other work arround that is "stronger" would be to add a customAttribute to Class3 that would be there to indicate that you cannot call the fonction. At this point in the parent method get the type of the current instance and via reflection verify if that the specified atribute is not present. By working like this you "prevent" anyone from setting the boolean from my previous hack to true, call, and set it back to false.  Any programmer that wish to bypass this would be forced into removing the "restriction" from the class.